# What are the differences between the linux-virtual, linux-image-virtual, and linux-image-extra-virtual kernels in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, kernel

I'm wondering what the differences are between these kernels?

```
linux-virtual
linux-image-extra-virtual
linux-image-virtual
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can investigate using apt-cache:

```
$ apt-cache show linux-virtual
```

gives, among other things:

```
Depends: linux-image-virtual (= 3.16.0.25.26), linux-headers-virtual (= 3.16.0.25.26)
Description-en: Minimal Generic Linux kernel and headers
 This package will always depend on linux-image-virtual and
 linux-headers-virtual.
```

From the Depends line, linux-virtual is used as a [meta-package](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages) to install linux-image-virtual and linux-header-virtual.

```
$ apt-cache show linux-image-virtual
```

gives:

```
Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-23-generic
Description-en: This package will always depend on the latest minimal generic kernel image.
 This package will always depend on the latest minimal generic kernel image
 used for virtual instances.
```

Running:

```
$ apt-cache show linux-image-extra-virtual
```

gives:

```
Depends: linux-image-generic (= 3.16.0.23.24) 
Description-en: Transitional package.
 This package will always depend on linux-image-generic.
```

There is a subtle difference here in the Depends line. You can see the same using the above command:

```
$ apt-cache show linux-image-generic
```

lists these dependencies:

```
Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-23-generic, linux-image-extra-3.16.0-23-generic, linux-firmware, thermald
```

In essence, linux-image-generic pulls extra dependencies on top of linux-image-extra-VERSION-generic. Take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/503034/40956) for more details.

To summarize:

- linux-virtual installs linux-image-virtual and linux-headers-virtual
- linux-image-virtual is identical to linux-image-VERSION-generic
- linux-image-extra-virtual is a superset of linux-image-virtual and is identical to linux-image-generic